# Trying to delete comments from code inputed by user C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, erase

```
string code;
cout << "Enter code\n";
getline(cin, code, '~');

size_t comment = code.find('/*');
size_t second = code.find('*/', comment);
size_t first = code.rfind('/*', comment);


code.erase(first, second - first);


cout << code << '\n';
```

**INPUT**

```
/*comment

comment*/

okay~
```

**OUTPUT**

```
//

okay
```

=============

the program deletes everything between /* */ , but won't delete the  / /. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm surprised you aren't getting compiler warnings about putting two characters inside a character literal.  You should use double quotes (`"`) to denote the string you want to find.

Comment: And you should test very carefully with input that contains incomplete comments or comments that contain `/*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're missing two backslashes,

Actually, you should use

```
code.erase(first-1, second - first+2);
```

this is happening because `string.erase(first,last)` removes characters in range of [ first , last )

i.e. it includes first but excludes last,

Note : First character in string is denoted by value 0 ( not 1 ).

I hope that helps
for more information refer [this webpage](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/)

Comment: is there any difference in my code `(second - first)+2` and your code `second - first+2` ?

Comment: @Rustam Well, can you justify what your code is doing. and like I said there's nothing wrong with that piece, actually, `first-1` should be first argument and not `first`, just try to run your code and you'll get to know it.

Comment: do you think you can represent two character in single quote like this '/*'?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
size_t comment = code.find("/*");        
size_t second = code.find("*/", comment); // here it returns the index from where `*/` starts so you      should also delete these two charater that why i added 2 in erase function.
size_t first = code.rfind("/*", comment);


code.erase(first, (second - first)+2);  
cout << code << '\n';
```

Comment: you're deleting characters from code ( which are part of source code) and missing one (precisely speaking, first backslash )
see my answer.

Comment: @DigitalBrain did you run it..?

Comment: @DigitalBrain in c++ 11 its working fyn. also here i m check as string  `code.find("/*");` not `code.find('/*');`

Comment: my bad! I just added +2 in asker's code, and executed, But still your code can bite, I mean after 49 years it will.