# deleting ALL comment lines that start with // c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, comments, erase

```
string str;

cout << "Enter code\n";
getline(cin, str, '~');

    //some loop i can't figure out
        size_t nFPos = str.find('//');
        size_t second = str.find('\n', nFPos);
        size_t first = str.rfind('\n', nFPos);
        str.erase(first, second - first);
   //end unknown loop
```

**INPUT**

code

//comment

//COMMENT

code~

**OUTPUT**

code

//COMMENT

code

I cannot for the life of me figure out what kind of loop I should use for it to delete ALL comments starting with //. It's only deleting the first comment and bypassing everything else.

I've tried for, while, do while, and if

I can't figure it out

Comment: Here is a solution to read variable input via cin:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201992/how-to-read-until-eof-from-cin-in-c

Comment: I can give you loop, but problems that could arise due to `//` in code is another problem, which is not at all mentioned here.

Comment: What exactly are you building, I answered [ your previous question ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26199788/trying-to-delete-comments-from-code-inputed-by-user-c), I think it's going to be buggy

Comment: @DigitalBrain a program to read a user's input (code) then remove all comment lines, any extra spaces (anything more than 1 space) and count all tokens. then display the edited code.

Comment: That's great, good job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
while(true)
    {
        size_t nFPos = str.find('//');        
        if(nFPos + 1)
        {
            size_t second = str.find('\n', nFPos);
            size_t first = str.rfind('\n', nFPos);
            str.erase(first, second - first);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

as mentioned [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

While executing `std::find()`, If no matches were found, the function returns `string::npos`

which is defined as 
`static const size_t npos = -1;`

So whenever a match will be found it'll return the position of the first character of the first match, (so it'll be non `-1` ).

If it is unable to find any match it'll return `-1` and `else` section will be executed (because `-1+1=0` and `0` is equivalent to `false` ), taking us out of the loop

Comment: i know it says to avoid comments like "thanks" .. but I just have to thank you. You answered both my questions and I'm really grateful!

Comment: @cynthiao You can say thanks by upvoting, I'm not forcing you!!

Comment: @cynthiao oops you're not allowed to

Comment: @cynthiao I think now you can

Comment: Why the endless loop with a break? Why not "`while (npos != (nFPos = str.find("//")) ) {}`" ?